# How can I access the "Content-Type" header of an NSHTTPURLResponse?

Tags: ios, swift, content-type, nshttpurlresponse

Here's my naive first pass code:

```
var httpUrlResponse: NSHTTPURLResponse? // = (...get from server...)
let contentType = httpUrlResponse?.allHeaderFields["Content-Type"]
```

I've tried various derivations of this code, but I keep getting compiler warnings/errors related to the basic impedance mismatch between the NSDictionary type of the allHeaderFields property and my desire to just get a String or optional String.

Just not sure how to coerce the types.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do something like the following in Swift 3:

```
if
    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, 
    let contentType = httpResponse.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") 
{
    // use contentType here
}
task.resume()
```

Obviously, here I'm going from the `URLResponse` (the `response` variable) to the `HTTPURLResponse`. And rather than fetching `allHeaderFields`, I’m using [`value(forHTTPHeaderField:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/httpurlresponse/3240613-value) which is typed and uses case-insensitive keys.

Hopefully this illustrates the idea.

For Swift 2, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25613226/4).

Comment: Why do you need to cast it to NSString before casting it to String? Wouldn't `as? String` work?

Comment: That double casting was an early Swift 2 problem, which is now rendered unnecessary. But the use of `value(forHTTPHeaderField:)`, shown in this revised answer, eliminates the `String` cast that `allHeaderFields` required, altogether.

Answer (score 2):

This works with Xcode 6.1:

```
let contentType = httpUrlResponse?.allHeaderFields["Content-Type"] as String?
```

Multiple casts no longer required.

And in Xcode 6.3 with Swift 1.2, this works:

```
let contentType = httpUrlResponse?.allHeaderFields["Content-Type"] as? String
```

Comment: The second statement works even pre-1.2, but I guess it didn't in September?

Answer (score 1):

I use an extension to URLResponse to simplify this one (Swift 3):

```
extension URLResponse {

    func getHeaderField(key: String) -> String? {
       if let httpResponse = self as? HTTPURLResponse {
           if let field = httpResponse.allHeaderFields[key] as? String {
                return field
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use the `MIMEType` property?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLResponse/MIMEType